Error reading csv.xz file using polars in python
I have a large file 'myfile.csv.xz' that I want to read using the polars package. When I do pl.read_csv(myfile.csv.xz) it fails with error ComputeError: invalid utf-8 sequance. If I do pl.read_csv(myfile.csv) or pl.read_csv(lzma.open(myfile.csv.xz)), it works fine.
The encoding of the file seems to the just ascii, so a subset of utf-8 I suppose?
How do I diagnose the error and possibly fix it?

I don't think Polars claims to support reading XZ files directly as of yet? https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues?q=xz+csv

I think I got fooled by trusting ChatGPT :( thanks!
